# Runtime Error 424 Object Required (Add Data in Data Entry Userform)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and did not have any background at all. I just watched youtube videos and try to learn. I'm making a data entry for shipment summary information. However, I experienced a `Runtime Error 464` when I run my Userform. I've checked my codes over and over and couldn't figure out the solution. Thanks in advance to those who'd help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim TextBox As String
    Dim Database As Worksheet
    Set Database = Worksheets("ShipData")

    eRow = ThisWorksheet.ShipData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 1).Value = TextBox6.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.List
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ComboBox2.List
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 3).Value = TextBox1.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 4).Value = TextBox2.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 5).Value = TextBox3.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 6).Value = ComboBox3.List
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox4.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 11).Value = TextBox7.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox8.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox9.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox10.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 15).Value = TextBox11.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 16).Value = TextBox12.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 17).Value = TextBox13.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 18).Value = TextBox14.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox15.Text
    ShipData.Cells(eRow, 20).Value = TextBox16.Text

    Unload Me
    ShipmentSummary.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: what is `eRow = ThisWorksheet.ShipData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` ? what is `ThisWorksheet.ShipData` ?

Comment: Check on `Combobox.List`. I think you're better off with `Combobox.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You already `Set` your `"ShipData"` worksheet with `Set Database = Worksheets("ShipData")`, so you can now reference it with `Database`, and not `ThisWorksheet.ShipData`.

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TextBox As String
Dim Database As Worksheet

Set Database = Worksheets("ShipData")

With Database
    eRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    .Cells(eRow, 1).Value = TextBox6.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.List  '<-- better use ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ComboBox2.List  '<-- better use ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(eRow, 3).Value = TextBox1.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 4).Value = TextBox2.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 5).Value = TextBox3.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 6).Value = ComboBox3.List  '<-- better use ComboBox3.Value
    .Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox4.Text  '<-- better use ComboBox4.Value
    .Cells(eRow, 11).Value = TextBox7.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox8.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox9.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox10.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 15).Value = TextBox11.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 16).Value = TextBox12.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 17).Value = TextBox13.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 18).Value = TextBox14.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox15.Text
    .Cells(eRow, 20).Value = TextBox16.Text
End With

Unload Me
ShipmentSummary.Show

End Sub
```